# Delete certain ajax call from URL

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping

I just got into web scraping with python, and im facing a problem.

Im scraping through various pages of `https://upplysing.se`, and need to erase a certain part from the href of the pagination button. 
The href is structured as followed:

```
https://upplysning.se/person/?x=1204&where=Sveav%e4gen+Stockholm&m=1&sl=detail&page=2
```

I need to delete the `&sl=detail` part from the url, but dont fully understand how to do that. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this

```
import urllib.parse as urlparse
url = 'https://upplysning.se/person/?x=1204&where=Sveav%e4gen+Stockholm&m=1&sl=detail&page=2'
parsed = urlparse.urlparse(url)

url = url.replace('&sl='+urlparse.parse_qs(parsed.query)['sl'][0],'')
print(url)#prints https://upplysning.se/person/?x=1204&where=Sveav%e4gen+Stockholm&m=1&page=2
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! Will accept the answer when possible.

Comment: Edit: this module messes up the special characters in the URL, which makes the url invalid, so unfortunately it does not work

Comment: @PerrivandenBerghe i have updated the code you can use it

Answer (score 0):

You could use urllib to the max and decompose the whole url into parts, remove the `sl` part, and recompose the whole:

```
def remove_url_query_arg(urlstring, argname):

  url = urlparse(urlstring)
  query = url.query
  args = parse_qsl(query)

  clean_args = [(k, v) for k, v in args if k != argname]

  clean_query = urlencode(clean_args)
  clean_url = urllib.parse.ParseResult(
    scheme=url.scheme,
    netloc=url.netloc,
    path=url.path,
    params=url.params,
    fragment=url.fragment,
    query=clean_query)

  return urlunparse(clean_url)
```

This leaves the knowledge of extracting and inserting stuff in and out of url strings where it belongs.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, still very new to python but things like this help me understand it more and more :)